# Override getText's EditText

Tags: android, android-edittext, spannablestring

I want to override `getText()` of EditText.

I receive this kind of String: `"12,345,678"`

My purpose is to just remove the commas and return the Editable but when with my code I get an error.

```
public class AmountEditText extends EditText {
    @Override
    public Editable getText() {
        Editable s = super.getText();
        if(s!=null && s.length()>0) {
            if (s.toString().contains(",")) {
                return new SpannableStringBuilder(s.toString().replace(",", ""));
            }
        }
        return s;
    }
    private TextWatcher watcher = new TextWatcher() {



        @Override
        public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count, int after) {

        }

        @Override
        public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) {
            int position = getSelectionStart();
            int nbCommaBefore;
            int nbCommaAfter;
            String str = s.toString();
            String finalStr;
            String formattedStr;
            nbCommaBefore  = str.length() - str.replace(",", "").length();
            boolean containsDot = false;
            if (str.contains(".")) {
                containsDot = true;
                formattedStr = str.split("\\.")[0];

            } else {
                formattedStr = str;
            }
            if (!s.toString().isEmpty()) {
                removeTextChangedListener(watcher);
                formattedStr = formattedStr.replace(",", "");
                formattedStr = formattedStr.replaceAll("(\\d)(?=(\\d{3})+$)", "$1,");
                if (containsDot) {
                    if (str.split("\\.").length != 1) {
                        finalStr = formattedStr + "." + str.split("\\.")[1].replace(",", "");
                    } else {
                        finalStr = formattedStr + ".";
                    }
                } else {
                    finalStr = formattedStr;
                }
                nbCommaAfter  = finalStr.length() - finalStr.replace(",", "").length();
                setText(finalStr);
                if (position == str.length()){
                    setSelection(finalStr.length());
                }
                else if (position == 0)
                {
                    setSelection(0);
                }
                else if (nbCommaBefore < nbCommaAfter){
                    setSelection(position + 1);
                }

                else if (nbCommaAfter < nbCommaBefore){
                    setSelection(position - 1);
                }
                else{
                    setSelection(position);
                }
                addTextChangedListener(watcher);
            }
        }

        @Override
        public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {
        }

    };

    public AmountEditText(Context context) {
        this(context, null);
    }

    public AmountEditText(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
        super(context, attrs);
        addTextChangedListener(watcher);
    }

    public AmountEditText(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyleAttr) {
        super(context, attrs, defStyleAttr);
        addTextChangedListener(watcher);
    }
}
```

> E/MessageQueue-JNI: Exception in MessageQueue callback:
>   handleReceiveCallback E/MessageQueue-JNI:
>   java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException: setSpan (0 ... 5) ends beyond
>   length 4
>           at android.text.SpannableStringBuilder.checkRange(SpannableStringBuilder.java:1265)
>           at android.text.SpannableStringBuilder.setSpan(SpannableStringBuilder.java:684)
>           at android.text.SpannableStringBuilder.setSpan(SpannableStringBuilder.java:677)
>           at android.widget.SpellChecker$SpellParser.setRangeSpan(SpellChecker.java:532)
>           at android.widget.SpellChecker$SpellParser.parse(SpellChecker.java:515)
>           at android.widget.SpellChecker.spellCheck(SpellChecker.java:242)
>           at android.widget.Editor.updateSpellCheckSpans(Editor.java:679)
>           at android.widget.Editor.sendOnTextChanged(Editor.java:1249)
>           at android.widget.TextView.sendOnTextChanged(TextView.java:8191)
>           at android.widget.TextView.setText(TextView.java:4483)
>           at android.widget.TextView.setText(TextView.java:4337)
>           at android.widget.EditText.setText(EditText.java:89)
>           at android.widget.TextView.setText(TextView.java:4312)
>           at org.newtonproject.newpay.widgetlib.AmountEditText$1.onTextChanged(AmountEditText.java:74)

I would like to precise that the error doesn't come from my onTextChanged
because everything works well without the `getText() override`

**EDIT** : The user can enter number, I will append some commas in order to format the number. But when I override `getText()` I want to delete these commas in that way I don't have to filter the return of `getText()` everytime

Comment: post your class code

Comment: done @ManojPerumarath

Comment: which line is n° 74 ?

Comment: setText(finalStr) @PierGiorgioMisley

Comment: thanks for explaination :)

Comment: _"the error doesn't come from my onTextChanged"_ The crash log says that it does. You should debug that method step by step and pay attention to any places where you use an index based on a string length as that would be a typical place for making a mistake.

Comment: @PierGiorgioMisley I edited my post to precise my purpose.

Comment: @MarkusKauppinen yes this is what the changelog is saying but the first error is coming from SpannableStringBuilder because I return a new Spannable. As I said, when I remove the getText() override. i don't have any problem with my getText()

Comment: " will append some commas in order to format the number. But when I override getText() I want to delete these commas in that way I don't have to filter the return of getText() everytime" - Couldn't you just apply a `DecimalFormat` on the way in and way out? It seems like that would be much simpler and more robust

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your case, you can not override `getText()` and resize and using `TextWatcher` at same time.

Check the android source code below and you will why

**SpannableStringBuilder.java**

```
public void setSpan(Object what, int start, int end, int flags) {
    setSpan(true, what, start, end, flags, true/*enforceParagraph*/);
}

private void setSpan(boolean send, Object what, int start, int end, int flags,
            boolean enforceParagraph) {
    checkRange("setSpan", start, end);
}

private void checkRange(final String operation, int start, int end) {
    ...
    int len = length();
    if (start > len || end > len) {
        throw new IndexOutOfBoundsException(operation + " " +
                    region(start, end) + " ends beyond length " + len); // here is you exception
    }
}

public int length() {
    return mText.length - mGapLength;
}
```

**SpellChecker.java**

```
private void setRangeSpan(Editable editable, int start, int end) {
    ...
    editable.setSpan(mRange, start, end, Spanned.SPAN_EXCLUSIVE_EXCLUSIVE);
}

public void parse(int start, int end) {
    ...
    if (parseEnd > start) {
        setRangeSpan((Editable) mTextView.getText(), start, parseEnd); // I think the error happened from here, they use your getText() function here and receive shorter string, but the start, parseEnd still stick with original string
        parse();
    }
}
```

**Solution** .
You can simple defind a new function like `getBeautifulText()`.

Answer (score 2):

Ok, I debugged that and found out that the problem was on that line

```
if (position == str.length()){
    setSelection(finalStr.length());
}
```

`lenght()` is out of bound for a set selection, since it's 0 based

just change your code with that and it will work properly

```
if (position == str.length()){
   setSelection(finalStr.length() - 1);
}
```

If needed, full code here (I used AppCompatEditText, but it's the same):

```
public class AmountEditText extends android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatEditText {
    @Override
    public Editable getText() {
        Editable s = super.getText();
        if(s!=null && s.length()>0) {
            if (s.toString().contains(",")) {
                return new SpannableStringBuilder(s.toString().replace(",", ""));
            }
        }
        return s;
    }
    private TextWatcher watcher = new TextWatcher() {



        @Override
        public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count, int after) {

        }

        @Override
        public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) {
            int position = getSelectionStart();
            int nbCommaBefore;
            int nbCommaAfter;
            String str = s.toString();
            String finalStr;
            String formattedStr;
            nbCommaBefore  = str.length() - str.replace(",", "").length();
            boolean containsDot = false;
            if (str.contains(".")) {
                containsDot = true;
                formattedStr = str.split("\\.")[0];

            } else {
                formattedStr = str;
            }
            if (!s.toString().isEmpty()) {
                removeTextChangedListener(watcher);
                formattedStr = formattedStr.replace(",", "");
                formattedStr = formattedStr.replaceAll("(\\d)(?=(\\d{3})+$)", "$1,");
                if (containsDot) {
                    if (str.split("\\.").length != 1) {
                        finalStr = formattedStr + "." + str.split("\\.")[1].replace(",", "");
                    } else {
                        finalStr = formattedStr + ".";
                    }
                } else {
                    finalStr = formattedStr;
                }
                nbCommaAfter  = finalStr.length() - finalStr.replace(",", "").length();
                setText(finalStr);
                if (position == str.length()){
                    setSelection(finalStr.length() - 1);
                }
                else if (position == 0)
                {
                    setSelection(0);
                }
                else if (nbCommaBefore < nbCommaAfter){
                    setSelection(position + 1);
                }

                else if (nbCommaAfter < nbCommaBefore){
                    setSelection(position - 1);
                }
                else{
                    setSelection(position);
                }
                addTextChangedListener(watcher);
            }
        }

        @Override
        public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {
        }

    };

    public AmountEditText(Context context) {
        this(context, null);
    }

    public AmountEditText(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
        super(context, attrs);
        addTextChangedListener(watcher);
    }

    public AmountEditText(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyleAttr) {
        super(context, attrs, defStyleAttr);
        addTextChangedListener(watcher);
    }
}
```

Let me know if that helped!

Comment: It helped thank you but finally, I will just implement a brand new method as another user suggested. Thank you !

Answer (score 0):

Try this one it will help's you

```
editText.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {
            boolean isEdiging;

            public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) {
            }

            public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count, int after) {
            }

            public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {
                if (isEdiging) return;
                isEdiging = true;
                String str = s.toString().replaceAll("[^\\d]", "");
                double s1 = 0;
                try {
                    s1 = Double.parseDouble(str);
                } catch (NumberFormatException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
                NumberFormat nf2 = NumberFormat.getInstance(Locale.ENGLISH);
                ((DecimalFormat) nf2).applyPattern("###,###.###");
                s.replace(0, s.length(), nf2.format(s1));

                if (s.toString().equals("0")) {
                    editText.setText("");
                }
                isEdiging = false;
            }
        });
```

Comment: i will clarify what I want from this EditText class

Answer (score 0):

Based on the requirements in your question:

> The user can enter number, I will append some commas in order to
>   format the number. But when I override getText() I want to delete
>   these commas

I believe you could use a much simpler solution involving `DecimalFormat`:

```
class Formatter {
    private final DecimalFormat f = new DecimalFormat(",###");
    private final DecimalFormat o = new DecimalFormat("#");

    String withCommas(String in) {
        try {
            return withCommas(Long.parseLong(in));
        } catch (NumberFormatException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            return withCommas(Long.MIN_VALUE);
        }
    }

    String withCommas(long in) {
        return f.format(in);
    }

    Number stripCommas(String in) {
        try {
            return f.parse(in);
        } catch (ParseException e) {
            return Long.MIN_VALUE;
        }
    }

    String stripCommasAsString(String in) {
        return o.format(stripCommas(in));
    }
}
```

Which gives:

```
final long num = 12345678L;
final Formatter f = new Formatter();

assertEquals("12,345,678", f.withCommas("12345678"));
assertEquals("12,345,678", f.withCommas(num));
assertEquals(num, f.stripCommas("12,345,678");
assertEquals("12345678", f.stripCommasAsString("12,345,678"));
```